# Optional<T> в List<T>

Tags: java, list, коллекции, java-stream, optional

Java 8. 
   Можно ли преобразовать Optional в List?

Answer (score 1):

Если в `Optional` что-то есть, возвращаем список с этим одиночным объектом, иначе возвращаем пустой список.

```
public static <T> List<T> toList(Optional<T> opt) {
    return opt.isPresent()
            ? Collections.singletonList(opt.get())
            : Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Полагаю, что тернарник явно лишний. Если в Optional лежит лист, то его надо типизировать листом (если нет, то, соответственно, не надо). Привожу пример с типизацией ,поскольку без типизации ответ уже , посему ответы можно комбинировать

```
public static <T> List<T> optionalToList(Optional<List<T>>opt) {
    return opt.orElse(new ArrayList<>());
}
```